# WEXITSTATUS always returns 0

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, fork, wait

I am forking a process and running a `wc` command using `execl`. Now under correct arguments, it runs fine, but when I give a wrong file name, it fails, but in both the cases the return value of
`WEXITSTATUS(status)`
is always 0.

I believe there is something wrong with what I am doing, but I'm not sure what is. Reading man pages and Google suggests that I should get a correct value as per the status code.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid <0){
        printf("error condition");
    } else if(pid == 0) {
        printf("child process");
        execl("/usr/bin/wc", "wc", "-l", "/Users/gabbi/learning/test/xyz.st",NULL);
        printf("this happened");
    } else {
        int status;
        wait(&status);

        if( WIFEXITED( status ) ) {
            std::cout << "Child terminated normally" << std::endl;
            printf("exit status is %d",WEXITSTATUS(status));
            return 0;
        } else {     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you `#include <sys/wait.h>`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: unless `<iostream>` includes `<sys/wait.h>` (or `<unistd.h>` does), then the code would not compile without also including `<sys/wait.h>`.  (Having said that, it compiled OK on Mac OS X 10.8.5 with GCC 4.8.1 without an explicit `<sys/wait.h>`, much to my surprise!)  The mixture of `printf()` and `cout` is curious, shall we say.  It is C++ — just. But only just.  The `printf()` messages should end with a newline.  When I run the code, I get: `wc: /Users/gabbi/learning/test/xyz.st: open: No such file or directory` and
`Child terminated normally` and
`exit status is 1` — as desired.

Comment: "*... when I give a wrong file name ...*" please clarify which file name you are referring to.

Comment: To clarify, all this was a problem with Xcode. When I ran the same code from console, it worked without any problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was an xcode issue, running from console works fine. I am a Java guy, doing some assignments in CPP. Nevertheless, it might come handy to someone getting stuck at similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you supply a name of non existing file to `execl()` as 1st argument it fails. If this happens the program leaves without returning any specifiy value. So the default of `0` is returned.

You could fix the for example like this:

```
#include <errno.h>

...

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if(pid <0){
    printf("error condition");
  } else if(pid == 0) {
    printf("child process");
    execl(...); /* In case exec succeeds it never returns. */
    perror("execl() failed");
    return errno; /* In case exec fails return something different then 0. */
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the file name from argv to the child process

Instead of

```
 execl("/usr/bin/wc", "wc", "-l", "/Users/gabbi/learning/test/xyz.st",NULL);
```

Try this,

```
 execl("/usr/bin/wc", "wc", "-l", argv[1],NULL);
```

The output I got on my machine

```
xxx@MyUbuntu:~/cpp$ ./a.out test.txt 
6 test.txt
Child terminated normally
exit status is 0

xxx@MyUbuntu:~/cpp$ ./a.out /test.txt 
wc: /test.txt: No such file or directory
Child terminated normally
exit status is 1
```